# Images getting squished when embedded in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am working on a project to get better at Flask, and I am using an image which is stored in my assets file (maindirectory>static>assets>myimage). While I got the images to appear just fine, they are weirdly squished, regardless of how I adjusted their heights. These heights worked just fine when I built the pages and embedded in HTML, so I am a bit confused.

My embed:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/t1.jpg' )}}" height="30%">
```

[image: The squished image]

I embedded this image with

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/t1.jpg' )}}" height="30%">
```

I know it is properly grabbing the image since it's showing up, but it is squishing for reasons I cannot understand. I was expecting it to look like it did when I used
`<img src="../static/assets/t1.jpg">` (which looked fine)

Comment: Maybe it's related to the `height="30%"` and not to flask at all?

Comment: You TOLD it to limit the height to 30% of its container.  The width will expand to fill the container.  Perhaps you need to explore the `object-fit` attribute

Comment: img height should be in pixels: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_height.asp

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find one of these two options useful.

1. write object-fit:cover to img tag;
2. Write the width in percentages and the height:auto;